# Obj-C - Expand selected cell, collapse when unselected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to make it so that when my user taps on a cell, it expands from height 70 to 165, and when they select another cell, I want the previously selected to collapse, and the newly selected to expand. Seems like it should be simple, but when I use the code below, some cells stay expanded on occasion, causing things to overlap? How can I fix this?

**Note:** My tableviewcell xib is 165h (as data I want to show when the cell is expanded sits in the bottom half of it)

**ViewController.m**

```
  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        if([indexPath isEqual:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]]) {

            return 165.0;

        }

        return 70.0;

    }

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@interface tableView (){

    NSInteger value;

}

@property(weak, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    value = 0;
}




- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if(value == 1){
        value = 0;

    }
    else{
        value = 1;
    }
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    _selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    [self.tableView endUpdates];


}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (indexPath == _selectedIndexPath && value == 1) {

        return 285;
    }
    else{
        return 120;
    }
    return 120;

}
```

Hope That Helps!

Comment: This works perfectly if my xib is also set to 70h. That said, if I want labels to appear in the dropdown portion, I can't set my xib to 165h in order for this to work. Which doesn't make sense to me, as how else am I supposed to put anything in the bottom half of the drop down?

Comment: well you need to take the cell height = 165 in the xib and do all the designing stuffs. In the code, change where ever i put 120 -> 70 and 285 -> 165. When the code runs it will return the height of the cell as 70 but when the cell is selected it will return the height as 165

Comment: Tried that - and for some reason when I do as you said above (xib at 165), a select few cells are returned at 165 even when they aren't selected :/

Comment: Umm that strange but it happens and did happened with mee too I need to see your code then. If comfortable then you can mail me file at - Hemant.garg@appcodeindia.com or you can provide me your email ID i will send you a dummy project

Answer (score 0):

Declare a property

```
@property NSIndexPath*index;
```

//

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath == self.index) {
        return 165.0;
    }
    return 70.0;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      self.index = indexPath;
      [tableView reloadData];
}
```

//

Check this [Demo](http://www.mediafire.com/file/h0k3dr17487j601/jvjhvjhj.zip/file)

Comment: When I implement this and open my tableview, two of my 4 cells are already expanded? When I finally get them all closed, for some reason my last cell stays expanded...

Comment: you may be missing something , check the attached demo it uses the same code